# IntelliJ automatic updating of jsp files in GAE module stops working with server parameters --address=0.0.0.0

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I have a GAE module on IntelliJ and when I after I edit the jsp files in it I can just go to the web browser, hit refresh and the changes show up. The other day I needed to access this from a different computer so I added `--address=0.0.0.0` to the server parameters and after that changes to the jsp stopped showing up on the browser until I did a server restart. I removed the option and it started working again. Added it again and it stopped working, repeated several times, always the same result.

So how I can access the server from another computer yet have the ability to make changes and have those changes show up on the web browser without a server restart?

I am using an exploded war, and I have "update classes and resources" on both "on update" and "on frame deactivation".

This is with IntelliJ 13 on OSX 10.9

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the way you specify --address=0.0.0.0 needs to be slightly different.  Investigate "it stopped working" more deeply, look for error logs, try running the development server from the command line without IntelliJ to gather more symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make iDEA update the runtime project:

1. Automatic via `on frame deactivation`, which means that IDEA updates project when you switch to another app (usually browser), i.e. when IDEA looses window focus. This works "automagically" while you test on the same computer, because you usually switch between IDEA and browser (or mobile emulator).
2. Manually via `on update`, which requires you to manually click the update button (the green circular arrows) in IDEA inside the running project pane.